# Background Border of TextBlock

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to add border around TextBlock programatically in Windows Store Application.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create new project and add this code in `OnNavigatedTo` event.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = new TextBlock() 
    {
        Text = "...TextBlock with border...",
        FontSize = 20
    };

    //To get actual height and width of TextBlock
    tb.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, Window.Current.Bounds.Width, Window.Current.Bounds.Height));
    tb.Measure(new Size(Window.Current.Bounds.Width, Window.Current.Bounds.Height));

    var border = new Border() 
    {
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red),
        Height = tb.ActualHeight + 10,
        Width = tb.ActualWidth + 10
    };

    var rootGrid = (Grid)(((Page)this).Content);
    rootGrid.Children.Add(border);
    border.Child = tb;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to set Width and Height of the border to these constant values and measuring the TextBlock. The Border should automatically size itself to fit the content.

Comment: If i don't set then border then it is set to whole grid rather than textblock.

Comment: Unless you set Vertical-/Horizontal-Alignment properties to something other than Stretch.